# Slow Tabs in React Navigation v5 Top Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, tabnavigator

I have a few tabs that render Flatlists. When all the tabs are loaded the Tab navigator becomes slow. I want the tab to reload whenever a Tab is in focus. I also tried to use removeClippedSubviews={true} but it is not working.

```
<TopTabs.Navigator
      lazy={true}
      removeClippedSubviews={true}
      tabBarOptions={{
        labelStyle: {fontSize: 13, fontFamily: 'medium'},
        tabStyle: {width: 110},
        pressColor: '#ffbbbb',
        style: {backgroundColor: '#fbf4f4', elevation: 0, shadowOpacity: 0},
        activeTintColor: '#ff7f7f',
        inactiveTintColor: '#aaa',
        scrollEnabled: true,
        indicatorStyle: {
          height: 4,
          width: 70,
          marginLeft: 20,
          borderRadius: 5,
          backgroundColor: '#ff7f7f',
        },
      }}>
      <TopTabs.Screen
        name="Tab 0"
        component={Tab0}
      />
      <TopTabs.Screen
        name="Tab 1"
        component={Tab1}
      />
      <TopTabs.Screen
        name="Tab 2"
        component={Tab2}
      />
      <TopTabs.Screen
        name="Tab 3"
        component={Tab3}
      />
      <TopTabs.Screen
        name="Tab 4"
        component={Tab4}
      />
    </TopTabs.Navigator>
```

Comment: Is it slow with empty tabs or when you load your components ?

Comment: gets slow when the 4th tab is loaded

Comment: Better check the components of 4th tab then

Comment: Brother the components are same, as other Tabs, each Tab has a flatlist with 5 items. I am using React-redux to load the tabs in state, as react navigation top tabs does not refresh the tabs once loaded so on loading data the tabs are getting slow. If just removeClippedSubviews was working this would have fixed easily.

Comment: It is listed here : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator#removeclippedsubviews but does not seem to work

Comment: i understand, you can use the useFocuseffect to reload tabs when you focus them